# using parseInt to get a div element property always returns NAN

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hopw the answer is simple, but I swear I've wasted hours on this.

I'm trying to change the position of a div element using regular ol' javascript. First I need the element's initial top and left property values as an integer. I'm trying to use parseInt(element.style.top, 10)

The problem I have is that the initial (default) element.style.top and left values always return NaN. If I  specify a top and left value before trying to parse the values, it works fine... I'd like to be able to handle a situation where the values haven't been specified yet...

Please help

Comment: These CSS values are normally not simple numbers - they all have (an explicit or implied) type (em, pixels, % etc).

Comment: I believe parseInt() returns the numbers preceding an alpha character... So parseInt(100px) would return 100. No?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value may be coming out "NaN" because the CSS property value is "auto".  That happens a lot in IE.

Comment: Current trying this out in FF4. I've tried printing out the initial value of element.style.top (not parsing the value and using something.innerhtml) and the initial value Is completely blank.

Comment: Well, an empty string is also "Not a Number".  What you could try to do is use `~~ element.style.top` which will convert the empty string and `null` to zero (numeric).

Answer (score 1):

`element.offsetTop` or `element.offsetLeft` return integers (no parsing needed), have you tried that? `element.style.top` can be a number of things, like `auto`, `3em`, `20%`. In the case of `auto` `parseInt` returns NaN, in the other cases it may return a number, but not the number you need.

Comment: The offset functions return different values than style.top or style.left, I guess one takes into account the border and margin, the other doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You are querying for the style property (as set by for example CSS). However, you want the actual position of the element. Take a look [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html) on how to do that with Javascript.